# Techniques to find out USB 2.0 power issues

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power

I have a Dell Precision T3400 on Windows Xp Pro Sp3 and whenever i connect an external Hard drive, it dies after a few seconds. However the drive works fine in other computers. How can I debug USB power issues?

Comment: Does the external hard drive die or does the computer die? Does the external hard drive get its power from the USB or does it get its power from a power brick?

Comment: the drive dies...its powered from the USB

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be easy, but you could strip your USB cable and put one of the wires through an [amp clamp meter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEoQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-KfZvbjyBY&ei=ArYBUYGjEKrwigLX3YFQ&usg=AFQjCNERlU4lQ0SWhXxc1rKIvkss0B_zGA&bvm=bv.41524429,d.cGE) to see the draw. You could also plug in a powered hub into the computer to see if that makes a difference.